# Why does the stack trace for my jest tests point to the wrong line numbers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

When I run jest tests in my repo containing errors, the stack trace points to the wrong line numbers. This makes it very difficult to debug. For example:

### Expected error

```
  ● SimpleComponent › renders

    ReferenceError: retur is not defined

      4 | export const Simple = () => {
      5 |   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    > 6 |   retur (
        |   ^
      7 |     <div>
      8 |       <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      9 |       <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>

      at Simple (src/SimpleComponent.jsx:6:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tst/SimpleComponentTest.jsx:8:5)
```

### Received error

Note that it's pointing to the wrong line number - 34 instead of 6.

```
  ● SimpleComponent › renders

    ReferenceError: retur is not defined



      at Simple (src/SimpleComponent.jsx:34:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tst/SimpleComponentTest.jsx:14:23)
```

### My findings

I found that if I comment out the [moduleDirectories](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#moduledirectories-arraystring) entry in `jest.config.js`, then I get the expected error message. I don't understand why `moduleDirectories` has such an impact though.

However, I want to keep my `moduleDirectories`.

### Question

Why does the stack trace for jest tests point to the wrong line numbers? How can I fix it?

### Files

I have uploaded a minimal example in https://github.com/bluprince13/jest-wrong-line-numbers-in-stack-trace

**Source**

Note that `return` statement is spelt wrong.

```
// src/SimpleComponent.jsx
import React, {useState} from "react"

export const Simple = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  retur (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Test**

```
// tst/SimpleComponentTest.jsx
import { Simple } from "../src/SimpleComponent";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";

describe("SimpleComponent", () => {
  it("renders", () => {
    render(<Simple />);
  });
});
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        [
            "@babel/preset-env"
        ]
    ]
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  moduleDirectories: [
    "<rootDir>/src",
    "<rootDir>/tst",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules"
  ],
  testMatch: ["**/tst/**/(*)Test.js?(x)", "**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --runInBand"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.14.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
        "snapshot-diff": "^0.6.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "^25.2.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.x",
        "@babel/preset-react": "7.x",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.2.0",
        "jest": "^26.6.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to reverse the order in moduleDirectories

Comment: That it points to the wrong line, has somehow to do with the source maps. For me, it seems to work, if I remove the `<rootDir>` string token

Comment: `"<rootDir>/node_modules",`=> `"node_modules",`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the stack trace for jest tests point to the wrong line numbers? How can I fix it?

It has to do with source maps. If those are not correctly generated or processed, the debugger will show the wrong line.

I found three ways how to fix this issue:

1. Changing `<rootDir>/node_modules` to `node_modules` in your
   `moduleDirectories`

   Why does this fix the issue?

   - If `<rootDir>` is added,
     jest or more precisely its underlying module `source-map-support` uses the `source_map` module from `node_modules/source-map`. Which in my case with a fresh install of your example, is `0.7.3`. But the `source_map_support` relies on `^0.6.0`. It actually brings the right version under `node_modules/source-map-support/source-map`. But for some reason with the `<rootDir>` specified, it can't access it anymore. And that brings us to the second solution.
2. Downgrade the `source-map` module to `^0.6.0` by manually including it as a dependency of your project. In that case `node_modules/source-map` will provide the right version again, but that might break something else, since it is not clear, where this wrong version is originating from.
3. Upgrade your project dependencies to the newest version.
   try `npm outdated` and you will see, that they are all outdated:
   [image]

Comment: I use the jest 29.3.1 , set moduleDirectories with `[
    'node_modules'
  ]`, but it does not work.

Answer (score -3):

I believe there is a bug, which counts the empty lines as well.

One solution I found from an open issue on Github - remove `"<rootDir>/src"` from `jest.config.js`. Is it a must to keep it?

Comment: What empty lines? There aren't 34 lines in that file.

Yes, I'm already aware that `moduleDirectories` entry is causing the issue. I'd like to understand why though and if there's another way to fix it.